# Getting `System.Exception` when trying to connect launch connection from Delinea Privilege Vault

Tags: apple

I am trying to launch an RDP connection to a Windows target through my Privilege Vault server. When I click on the **Launch** button, the Vault Remote app opens on my macOS machine, but the RDP session doesn't start.

When I check the Vault Remote app logs, I see the following messages:

```
2022-12-21 22:48:09.2822|WARN|Thycotic.ConnectionManager.Mac.AppDelegate|Application started.
2022-12-21 22:48:09.2831|WARN|Thycotic.ConnectionManager.Mac.AppDelegate|App Version - 1.7.1.
2022-12-21 22:48:09.2843|WARN|Thycotic.ConnectionManager.Mac.AppDelegate|OS Version - Version 13.1 (Build 22C65).
2022-12-21 22:48:09.2848|WARN|Thycotic.ConnectionManager.Mac.AppDelegate|Processor - Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1038NG7 CPU @ 2.00GHz.
2022-12-21 22:48:09.2859|WARN|Thycotic.ConnectionManager.Mac.AppDelegate|Physical Memory - 16 GiB.
2022-12-21 22:48:09.2859|WARN|Thycotic.ConnectionManager.Mac.AppDelegate|
2022-12-21 22:48:11.8204|WARN|A.cf2a769b451d4c392516a68beb0ec7aa5|Failed to load user settings from file. Default settings will be used.
2022-12-21 22:48:13.1462|ERROR|A.cba22f25d4b712c6b69cfd6e45d56057c|System.Exception: Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown.
  at A.cba22f25d4b712c6b69cfd6e45d56057c.c1d2034a330668b2265542cd96165d7ef (System.Guid cf3cdf3dfff0880a03d5331b52d6bad85, System.Int32 cf47be96c20c6be5dd31ad79a3937495a) [0x00105] in <6da488f2db0b4b4daddda988447ccb0a>:0
```

- My macOS machine definitely has RDP privileges to the target.
- The username/password for the target is correct (the heartbeat is successful).
- This was working previously but hasn't worked since upgrading to macOS Ventura.
- There have been no changes to the Privilege Vault server or firewall settings.
- I've reinstalled the ConnectionManager several times.

Comment: Only your vendor will be able to decipher those messages.

Comment: I have a ticket open with the vendor. Once resolved, I will post the solution here.

Comment: It looks like they may have an obfuscator for the stack trace, which is not unusual. It's probably something where verbose logging would be useful, or a tool they can give you.